# How to reset Android Studio to previous version

Tags: android-studio, version, updates

I recently recklessly updated AS from 3.0.1 to 3.1, but project manager says 3.0.1 is the version to be worked with in our project. Is there a way to reset AS to version 3.0.1 without having to uninstall it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Currently there is no direct way with which a downgrade can be done. I managed to do the downgrade by downloading Android Studio 3.0.1 from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html) and then running the installer. It will prompt whether to uninstall previous version, and when you allow and proceed, it will remove 3.1 and install 3.0.1.

You need to ensure 3.1 is not running in background i.e. Close the Studio 3.1 application.

Comment: And does that delete any project files?

Comment: For me, it didn't delete any files. It worked as before.

Comment: @Sagar I have downloaded, only uninstall.exe and other folder are there. How to install ? Could you tell me.

Answer (score 6):

On Mac, just download desired version .app file from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive, then paste into Applications folder.

Comment: Works for linux too

Comment: There are also versions to download from there for Windows & ChromeOS.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 I went to Program Files/Android in File Explorer, right clicked on Android-Studio, deleted it, went and downloaded an older version of Android Studio from the archvies then installed it without any issues.

Answer (score -3):

i also updated to Bumblebee ..  just go to preferences and write "device manager" in search  choose keymap and set a shortcut key for device manger click apply and ok and use the new shortcut to get the Avd menue