# No builders are available to build a model of type 'org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.internal.DummyModel'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

After upgrading Android Studio to 4.0 version and in "gradle-wrapper.properties" :

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

I am getting the following error in Android Studio while syncing:
No builders are available to build a model of type 'org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.internal.DummyModel'.

and unable to create or run the app build.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be one solution. I tried Copy and Cut everything in the setting.gradle file located in the project directory then SYNC project after Gradle is complete. Later paste the content back to the file and SYNC again. This not worked for me but for others, it worked.

Another solution is to downgrade the android studio to v 3.6.3 download by [clicking here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592769/how-to-reset-android-studio-to-previous-version). You can follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592769/how-to-reset-android-studio-to-previous-version) to downgrade the android studio. This solution worked for me and now I can build and run the application successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by navigating to the Project settings in the **settings.gradle** file and COPY and CUT everything then SYNC the project after gradle is complete PASTE back the content you had copied and SYNC again.

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Still not worked

Please use different gradle version.

ie case gradle-wrapper.properties. Instead of your version

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-*.*.*-all.zip
```

update with

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above but I didn't succeed so I uninstall android studio and then installed it again and saw all the problems solved and I have no problem . so I recommend you reinstall the program as a last step .
REINSTALL