# Android Studio editing very laggy after update to Arctic Fox (windows)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

After updating to Arctic Fox, the editing is very laggy. I was trying to narrow it down to when it happens (since it's not happening all the time, but still often enough to annoy the heck out of me), so I'm about to uninstall/reinstall to 4.2.2 (I hope that's the last one I had, not sure how to check).

Anyone else seeing this? (it's not related to M1, this is on windows). Also not related to emulator (off) or database inspector afaict.

btw, no easy way to rollback a studio version apparently?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching your channel to Canary and download the Android Studio 2021.1.1 Bumblebee. You can install alongside also for testing out the preview build without hindering your existing installation. The link to preview and doc is here - https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features.

P.S. - I've tested canary and performance is super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately seems there's no way to [rollback the version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592769/how-to-reset-android-studio-to-previous-version#:%7E:text=Currently%20there%20is%20no%20direct,remove%203.1%20and%20install%203.0.) of Android Studio.

You can find [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) an archive of all the past Android Studio versions for download, and I also found this post on superuser about checking the [Uninstalled programs history on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/233621/uninstalled-programs-history-on-windows-7)

I hope it will be of some help, unfortunately I'm on mac and can't give you any advice for the slowdown

Comment: yeah, thanks, that's what I plan to do eventually if I can't find the root cause for the lag